# How to create an auto increment every time an object is created and decrements when it is "destroyed"

Tags: java, auto-increment

When I create an instance of the class actor I add the object faction.

```
//Constructor
Actor(String name, Race race, Faction faction){
    this.name = name;
    this.race = race;
    this.faction = faction;        
}
```

I wanted that every time the object **faction** is used by the **actor** the an auto count inside the object faction increments, and every time the object **actor** is destroyed it decrements.

```
public class Faction {

private String name;
private int membersNum;
private ArrayList<Faction> knowFactionList = new ArrayList<Faction>();
private ArrayList<Relation> factionRelationList = new ArrayList<Relation>();

  Faction(String name){
        this.name = name;        
   }  



public void addBattleMember(){
       membersNum++;
   }
   public void removeBattleMember(){
       membersNum--;
   }
```

I am now using this method inside the class Faction Manager to create the list and manually decreasing when the object actor stop being used.

```
 public void buildActiveFactionsOnBattle(ArrayList<Actor> actorList) {
    for (Actor act : actorList) {
        act.getFaction().addBattleMember();
        if (!activeFactionsOnBattle.contains(act.getFaction()))
            activeFactionsOnBattle.add(act.getFaction());
    }
}
```

Comment: the best way to do that is static variable, and increment it every time that actor using faction in the constructor

Comment: What do you mean by the "object is destroyed"? Do you mean when your app is done with it, or when it is garbage collected by the JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "the best way to do that is static variable, and increment it every
>   time that actor using faction in the constructor – Fady Saad 1 min
>   ago"

I would go this route as its much easier.

Somewhere in the class do something such as:

```
static int fractionCount = 0;
```

Static variables are such that all instances of, for say the fraction object, reference the same variable.

Changing the static variable from one class will change the variable for all instances of that class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook the logic somewhere under the user space in JVM. A native JVM agent is capable of doing it.

Refer https://github.com/JigarJoshi/jvm-objects-inspector